# The word "significant" is misspelt on answer-bans help centre page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center

The word "significant" is written as "signifciant" on the first paragraph on [the new answer-ban help page](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/answer-bans).

Comment: Sooo...do I change that title to ""Significant" misspelled on..." or "Significant misspell on..."?

Comment: Is that a signifciant problem for you?

Comment: Spleling nazi's everywere. Cna't a tpyo get a brake?

Comment: Argh, now I want a comment-edit feature request...or we could just ban @GeorgeCummins.

Comment: You (all) misspelled "center".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We were using the Chaucerian old English spelling convention to - oh, fine it was a typo.  Fixed - thanks!

Comment: Pacing problems in this answer. It starts with the setting, then jumps (hyphens) right to a plot twist, resolution and denounement... I prefer more conflict between the start and the end of narratives. Overall, I give it 3 stars, fun summer answer if you're looking for something to meta about, but I would not read again.